# Android Actionbar Split And Position Items

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I've made an ActionBar with action ActionBarSherlock and I've spitted it with

> android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"

How can I position the items now? All my items are at the bottom ActionBar, I want some at the top and some at the bottom ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [ActionBar guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar):

> Split action bar provides a separate bar at the bottom of the screen to display **all** action items when the activity is running on a narrow screen (such as a portrait-oriented handset).

If you want items on both the top ActionBar and buttons along the bottom, then you should use a regular ActionBar and add the buttons as a custom layout (perhaps using the [android.R.attr.borderlessButtonStyle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#borderlessButtonStyle)). However, you will not get the auto-collapsing into a single ActionBar on larger devices, but that can easily be done by creating a menu/layout specifically for wider devices using a selector like layout-w480dp on v14+ devices.